# focus on next element with "tabindex" but in next td

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this not work

I'm trying to focus on the next element in the next td with "tabindex" .

my elements dont have ids and all have the same tabindex

```
$('form').keypress(function (event) {

        $(":focus").parents('td').next('td').find('[tabindex]:first').focus(); //this is not working

    }

});


<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="TextBox1" type="text"  tabindex="1" /></td>
        <td><input name="TextBox2" type="text"  tabindex="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="TextBox3" type="text" tabindex="1" /></td>
        <td><input name="TextBox5" type="text"  tabindex="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                <select name="DropDownList1"  tabindex="1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
        </td>
        <td><input name="TextBox6" type="text" tabindex="1" /></td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="TextBox7" type="text" tabindex="1" /></td></td>
        <td><input name="TextBox8" type="text"  tabindex="1" /></td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Why do you have everything with tabindex 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uwdYm/1/)

```
$('form').keypress(function (event) {

        $(":focus").parents('td').next('td').find('[tabindex="1"]:first').focus(); //this is not working



});
​
```

Comment: thanks so much - but I see it does not jump to the next td in the next tr - any ideas? thanks

Comment: It is jumping check the jsfiddle. but if you want text to be entered in next td use keydown instead keypress.

Comment: thanks I checked but on mine it stops in the second TD of the row. do you know how to make it jump to the first input in the next row

Comment: I suggest you to check your code once again there may be some minor difference. or you can create jsfiddle using your code. so that test it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#Id:focus').find('input[tabindex=1]').focus()
```

and indexing you tabIndex